# Стандартные алгоритмы std::copy_backward и std::reverse_copy

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Не смог найти пример, когда удобнее использовать   `std::copy_backward` вместо   `std::reverse_copy`.  И чем же  существование второго не заставляет забывать о первом?   Можете привести такой пример(любой)?

Comment: `std::forward_list`

Comment: yrHeTaTeJlb, спс, кажется вы попали в точку, но могли бы и в ответе написать примерчик с ним. Думаю кому то будет полезно тоже

Comment: За такой ответ мне бы прилетело из очереди проверок :) А расписывать лень

Comment: [альгоритма] Я извиняюсь, но по-русски это слово пишется без мягкого знака - "алгоритм". И произносится и твердым звуком "л".

Comment: , спс за поправку

Comment: Вопрос изначально бессмыслен, ибо функции делают совершенно разные вещи.

Comment: @AnT,  для вас может и бессмыслен, но я же не для вас спрашивал...  Конечно записать в конец или в начало, разные функциональности, да и алгоритмы, как и контейнеры нужно  выбирать  руководствуясь  в основном по эффективности.   Ведь контейнеры тоже часто взоимозаменяемы, если не учитывать фактор эффективности. ..   Тут в одном применяется декремент, в другом инкремент, и даже этим они разные, но все же  ответы мне дали дополнительную полезную информацию, и мне нужен был пример, и лично для меня не  бессмыслен вопрос, и может быть для кого то еще...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Функции делаю *принципиально* разные и совершенно не совместимые вещи. Одна - копирует последовательность, другая - переворачивает последовательность. Поэтому вопроса об "какую удобнее использовать" не существует.

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Здесь нет никакого "моего мнения". То, что данные функции не являются взаимозаменяемыми - объективный факт, не зависящий ни от моего, ни от чьего-то еще мнения. Ваши попытки крутиться волчком и напускать словесный дым, вместо того чтобы просто признать, что вы элементарно поленились разобраться, что именно делают эти функции здесь никому не нужны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фактически, стандартные алгоритмы **std::copy** и **std::copy_backward** логически тесно связаны со стандартными строковыми C-функциями **strcpy** и **memmove**.

Первая строковая функция **strcpy** не допускает пересечения исходного диапазон и диапазона, куда происходит копирование.

Вторая строковая функция **memmove** позволяет работать с пересекающимися диапазонами.

Рассмотрите следующую демонстрационную C-программу.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    char s[N] = "12344321";

    puts( s );

    memmove( s + 5, s + 4, 4 );

    s[4] = '5';

    puts( s );

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
12344321
123454321
```

То есть чтобы вставить цифру **5** в середину строки, необходимо переместить вторую половину исходной строки на одну позицию вправо.

В этой программе нельзя заменить вызов **memmove** на вызов **strcpy**,

Как ту же самую операцию выполнить с помощью стандартных алгоритмов?

Соответствующая программа, к примеру, может выглядеть следующим образом.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;

    char s[N] = "12344321";

    std::cout << s << '\n';

    std::copy_backward( std::next( s, 4 ), std::next( s, 8 ), std::next( s, 9 ) );

    s[4] = '5';

    std::cout << s << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль будет таким же, как показано выше

```
12344321
123453321
```

Хотя указатели являются частными случаями итераторов произвольного доступа, но чтобы использовать приведенные программы, достаточно, чтобы указатели поддерживали пост-декрементную операцию --. То есть достаточно иметь двунаправленные итераторы.

И,действительно, алгоритм **std::copy_backward** определяется как

```
template<class BidirectionalIterator1, class BidirectionalIterator2>
constexpr BidirectionalIterator2 copy_backward( BidirectionalIterator1 first, 
                                                BidirectionalIterator1 last,
                                                BidirectionalIterator2 result );
```

Это означает, что алгоритм может применяться к последовательностям, которые имеют двусторонние итераторы. Например, стандартный класс **std::forward_list** имеет лишь последовательные итераторы. А это означает, что вы не можете использовать алгоритм **std::copy_backward** с объектами этого шаблонного класса.

С другой стороны, алгоритм **std::reverse_copy** определяется как

```
template<class BidirectionalIterator, class OutputIterator>
constexpr OutputIterator reverse_copy( BidirectionalIterator first, 
                                       BidirectionalIterator last,
                                       OutputIterator result );
```

Как видно из объявления алгоритма, второй шаблонный параметр допускает входной итератор. Поэтому, опять-таки, если используемый шаблонный аргумент для второго шаблонного параметра не является в то же время двусторонним итератором, то этот алгоритм нельзя будет использовать вместо алгоритма **std::copy_backward**, так как второй итератор этого алгоритма должен быть двусторонним для пересекающихся диапазонов (как это будет видно из представленной ниже демонстрационной программы).

Теперь допустим, что имеется контейнер, как, например, обычный массив, который имеет двусторонние итераторы (на самом деле указатели, которые используются в качестве итераторов для массивов, являются итераторами произвольного доступа).

Как можно было бы заменить вызов алгоритма **std::copy_backward** на вызов алгоритма **std::copy_reverse**?

Сделать это очень просто!

Ниже показана соответствующая демонстрационная программа.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    int b[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

    for ( const int *p = a; *p; ++p ) std::cout << *p << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    for ( const int *p = b; *p; ++p ) std::cout << *p << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::copy_backward( std::next( a, 4 ), 
                        std::next( a, 8 ), 
                        std::next( a, 9 ) );
    a[4] = 5;

    std::reverse_copy( std::next( b, 4 ),
                       std::next( b, 8 ), 
                       std::reverse_iterator( std::next( b, 9 ) ) );
    b[4] = 5;

    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( const int *p = a; *p; ++p ) std::cout << *p << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    for ( const int *p = b; *p; ++p ) std::cout << *p << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Вывод этой программы на консоль

```
1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 

1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
```

Однако, вышеприведенная программа некорректная! В требованиях к алгоритму **std::reverse_copy** указывается, что

> 4 Requires: The ranges [first, last) and [result, result + (last -
>   first)) **shall not overlap**.

То есть этот алгоритм, как и стандартная C-функция **strcpy** (и как стандартный алгоритм **std::copy**) не допускает пересечение диапазонов.

А, следовательно, не всегда алгоритм **std::copy_backward** можно заменить на алгоритм **std::copy_reverse**.

Comment: Может вместо `strcpy()` лучше рассматривать `memcpy()`? (все же strcpy сильно завязана на 0 в конце...)

Comment: @avp Да, можно в качестве примера рассмотреть memcpy вместо strcpy.

Answer (score 5):

### Эти две функции делают разные вещи.

`std::copy_backward` не меняет порядок элементов в диапазоне, а `std::reverse_copy` меняет. Кроме того, один копирует в конец целевого диапазона, а другой в начало.

Например:

```
std::vector<int> mas1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<int> mas2(8, 0);
std::vector<int> mas3(8, 0);
std::copy_backward(mas1.begin(), mas1.end(), mas2.end()); 
std::reverse_copy(mas1.begin(), mas1.end(), mas3.begin()); 
// mas2 = {0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
// mas3 = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0}
```

Comment: Ну почему не меняет?  Смысль альгоритма какраз состоит в  возможности копировать в обратном порядке. Попробуйте   std::copy_backward(mas1.rbegin(), mas1.rend(), mas2.end());

Comment: Код: http://cpp.sh/8zkqs , не меняет.

Comment: Вы не внимательно прочитали. Я предложил   использовать альгоритм с  reverse_iterator   для чтения

Comment: Точно, про reverse итератор я прощёлкал. Но всё равно, результат действия двух упомянутых функций различен: http://cpp.sh/3n4fm

Comment: Понятно, что  результат действий различны. Я не могу придумать пример, где  первый не может заменяться вторым, причем с большим удобством. Вопрос именно в этом_ мне нужен такой пример

Comment: Допишите в вопрос вариант, как одним заменить другой. Мне не очевиден вариант, который был бы более удобным.